# Need replacement for deprecated and removed API from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am actually using someone's code to learn NLP and in trying to run their code, came across this error:

```
File "ls-dlm.py", line 23, in <module>
    y = data.is_duplicate.values
  File "/Users/Abhishek/Projects/Python-Projects/Python-VEs/Log-Similarity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'is_duplicate'
```

**CODE**

```
data = pd.read_pickle("data/log_dataset.pkl")
y = data.is_duplicate.values
ytrain_enc = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
```

Clearly, the `is_duplicate` method no longer exists and I tried to dig some information up from archives and old documentation for Pandas, but came up empty handed.

Could someone please explain what this method is doing and how do I replace it with the latest API in the Pandas release?

Thank you so much for helping.

P.S : I am new to Pandas too, so I really have no clue how to replace it or what it even did in the first place. Hoping to get an answer for a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_duplicate` is not necessarily a Pandas **method** name.
It looks rather as a reference to a **column** with this name.

Look at `.values` after it. It seems to confirm my hypothesis, that:

- the program actually tries to find a **column** with this name
  (of *Series* type),
- then it refers to `values` attribute, i.e. tries to convert it to
  its *Numpy* representation (I came across a warning that one should
  use `to_numpy()` function instead).

Maybe you should "recreate" this column from existing data.
To do it, try to figure out, which columns of your DataFrame identify
a row as a **unique entity**. Then call:

```
df['is_duplicate'] = df.duplicated([<a_list_of_columns>])
```

and you will have the missing column.

Of course, you should to figure out, whether you look for **all** duplicates
or maybe all but the first instance (there is a relevant parameter of
`duplicated` function).

Another path to look: Check your DataFrame, maybe it already contains a column
with a **similar** name and `is_duplicate` in your code is a misspelled version
of the "proper" column name.

Comment: You are completely correct. I was so intent on tracing the error back that I overlooked that it could actually come from a column in the dataframe and may not be a method from Pandas itself. Thank you so much for that clear explanation. It helped me track the issue down.